# Sinatra suitability for building a helpdesk system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, sinatra

I want to build my own lightweight ticketing system and I wonder which tool should I use for this. As I want to code this app in ruby, I'm chosing between ruby frameworks, mainly Rails and Sinatra and I wonder which one is more suitable for that job.

Comment: it's a personal decision. You could do it in either one, it just depends if you prefer Sinatra (which is more lightweight and concise) or Rails (more monolithic and comprehensive). If you're a beginner, I recommend trying Sinatra first because it will be simpler to understand. Also, nearly every skill you learn with Sinatra will be directly applicable to Rails. Sinatra is like _rails lite_. By the way, unless you're building this in order to learn a web framework, it might be worth searching for a open-source project you can use instead of having to make your own app.

Comment: @maxpleaner That should be an answer! :) Very well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a personal decision. You could do it in either one, it just depends if you prefer Sinatra (which is more lightweight and concise) or Rails (more monolithic and comprehensive). If you're a beginner, I recommend trying Sinatra first because it will be simpler to understand. Also, nearly every skill you learn with Sinatra will be directly applicable to Rails. Sinatra is like rails lite. By the way, unless you're building this in order to learn a web framework, it might be worth searching for a open-source project you can use instead of having to make your own app.